# jquery delete all children except a div

Tags: jquery

How do I delete everything inside a `div` except a `div/span` with `class='notsure'`? I can delete all children using `empty` but not sure how to save a specific `div`.

```
<div id="test">
    here is a test
    <p>a paragraph</p>
    <div class="notsure"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
var save = $('#test .notsure').detach();
$('#test').empty().append(save);
```

Answer (score 13):

Update:

If you also want to remove text `here is a test`:

```
var notsure = $('.notesure');
$('#test').html('').append(notsure);
```

#### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/urudew)

---

```
$('#test').children().not('.notsure').remove();
```

Comment: That won't remove "here is a test"

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
$("#test").children().filter(":not(.notesure)").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter its content:

```
var b = $('#test').contents();

b.filter(function() {  //
    return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
}).remove()
.end().filter(':not(.notesure)').remove(); //Find the elements that don' t have the .notesure class.;


$('.notesure').click(function(){
    $(this).html('clicked !!');
}
```

Example. http://jsbin.com/urudew/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

#### Remove siblings but keep `.notsure`

```
$('.notsure').clone(true).appendTo($('#test').empty());
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rayehu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Remove `true` from `clone(true)` to get rid of `.notsure`'s bound events like *click* etc.
If you'e **not** interested in **events** bound to that elements, you can simply do:

```
$('.notsure').appendTo($('#test').empty());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check this Below is the working example

```
$(function () {
$('#delete-button').click(function () {
    deleteElementsBelow('#parent-container');
});

function deleteElementsBelow(parentContainerSelector) {
    var save = $('#parent-container #delete-button').detach();
            $(parentContainerSelector).empty().append(save);
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L9vdz7n7/

Answer (score -1):

a trick could be done here ...

```
$("#test").html('<div class="notesure">'+$('div.notesure').html()+'</div>')
```

Comment: That will remove any event listeners attached to `div.notesure`.